# help for an integral

Tags: integration, finance, economics

I need help calculating this integral:

> $$\int_0^x \frac{2(e^{\gamma u}-1)}{(\gamma+\kappa)(e^{\gamma u}-1)+2\gamma} du$$

I tried with the integration by parts but the situation seems to get worse.

I'm not a skillful mathematician (not even a mathematician) so any help would be appreciated. I just know it's possible to solve it since it pops out in a famous financial model but haven't found any derivation yet.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing the numerator and denominator of the integral by $\gamma + \kappa$ gives
$$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{a(e^{\gamma u}-1)du}{e^{\gamma u}-1+a\gamma}$$
Where $a=\frac2{\gamma + \kappa}.$

Breaking this into $2$ integrals,
$$=\frac a\gamma\int_{0}^x\frac{\gamma e^{\gamma u}du}{e^{\gamma u}-1+a\gamma}-a\int_0^x\frac{du}{e^{\gamma u}-1+a\gamma}$$

For the first, substitute $e^{\gamma u}-1=t$ and you're left with
$$\frac{a}{\gamma}\int \frac{dt}{t+a\gamma}$$
Do the same substitution for the second one, and you have
$$\frac{1}{\gamma}\int \frac{dt}{(t+1)(t+a\gamma)}$$
The first one is now standard, and the second can be done by partial fractions.

**Edit:**

> For the second integral, partial fractions isn't mandatory.

The second integral can be written as
$$\frac{1}{\gamma(a\gamma-1)}\int \frac{(t+a\gamma)-(t+1)dt}{(t+1)(t+a\gamma)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\gamma(a\gamma-1)}\int \frac{dt}{t+1}-\frac{1}{\gamma(a\gamma-1)}\int \frac{dt}{t+a\gamma}$$
Both of which are standard.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I'm going to carefully read what you wrote. However, I ask you: is this partial fractions method easy to face for, as I wrote, a non-math student? If not, can you go through it too?

Comment: @davidpaich it's quite simple and straightforward after a few examples. Here's a quick and simple rundown: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/partfrac.htm

Comment: @davidpaich see the edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Putting $\beta=\frac{2}{\gamma+\kappa}$ and $\alpha=\beta\gamma$ we have
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^x \frac{2(\mathrm e^{\gamma u}-1)}{(\gamma+\kappa)(\mathrm e^{\gamma u}-1)+2\gamma} \mathrm du=\beta\int_0^x \frac{(\mathrm e^{\gamma u}-1)}{(\mathrm e^{\gamma u}-1)+\alpha} \mathrm du\\&=\beta\int_0^x \frac{(\mathrm e^{\gamma u}-1)\color{blue}{+\alpha-\alpha}}{(\mathrm e^{\gamma u}-1)+\alpha} \mathrm du=\beta x-\alpha\beta\int_0^x \frac{1}{(\mathrm e^{\gamma u}-1)+\alpha} \mathrm du\\
&=\beta x-\alpha\beta J
\end{align}
Putting $\delta=\alpha-1$ and with the substitution $\mathrm e^{\gamma u}=z$, 
$$
J=\int_0^x \frac{1}{(\mathrm e^{\gamma u}-1)+\alpha} \mathrm du=\int_0^{\mathrm e^{\gamma x}} \frac{1}{z+\delta} \frac{\mathrm dz}{\gamma z}=\frac{1}{\delta\gamma} \int_0^{\mathrm e^{\gamma x}} \left[ \frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z+\delta}\right]\mathrm dz=\frac{1}{\delta\gamma}\Big[\log z-\log(z+\delta)\Big]_0^{\mathrm e^{\gamma x}}=\frac{x}{\delta}-\frac{1}{\delta\gamma}\log\left(\mathrm e^{\gamma x}+\delta\right)
$$
Finally
$$
I=\beta x-\alpha\beta\left[\frac{x}{\delta}-\frac{1}{\delta\gamma}\log\left(\mathrm e^{\gamma x}+\delta\right)\right]=\frac{\beta}{1-\beta\gamma} \Big[x+\beta \log\left(\mathrm e^{\gamma x}+\beta\gamma-1\right)\Big]
$$